# Node mysql: como esperar que la funcion conn.query termine?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Mi problema es que el objeto newUser que trae la consulta a la base de datos debe ser modificado, asignandole un id, esto ocurre bien dentro de conn.query. pero al salir de conn.query y req.getConnection este id no se modifico, al revisar los console.log no se esta esperando que las funciones  **conn.query** y **req.getConnection** terminen y se sigue normalmente con el codigo, necesito hacer que se espere de alguna forma a que conn.query y req.getConnection terminen para continuar. no se como hacerlo

```
  req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
      conn.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', [newUser], (err, user) => {
      if(err) {
        res.json(err);
      }
      newUser.id =  user.insertId;
    console.log(newUser)
  
    })
  })
  (console.log("OUT!"))
  console.log(newUser)  }));
```

retorna :

```
OUT!
{
  username: 'cc',
  password: '$2a$10$oaAEq3Ninr1CGCzxk3gD.eJZLyRIb4L10f814KzafvpMky6KY2iHK',
  fullname: 'cc'
}
{
  username: 'cc',
  password: '$2a$10$oaAEq3Ninr1CGCzxk3gD.eJZLyRIb4L10f814KzafvpMky6KY2iHK',
  fullname: 'cc',
  id: 55
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué módulo estás utlizando? Y otra cosa, ¿a qué te refieres con "modificar", quieres que ese cambio se refleje en la base de datos o solo en dentro del código? Porque si lo que quieres es actualizar en base de datos, te está faltando el `UPDATE`.

Comment: No, no se debe reflejar en base de datos, solo dentro del codigo. modulo: mysql

Comment: Antes de poder darte una respuesta, puedes revisar tu código, lo he copiado y pegado y parece que tiene paréntesis y corchetes de más. Adicionalmente, ¿podrías colocar algo dentro del `console.log` que está dentro del callback de `getConnection`?, para poder diferenciarlo del que dice "OUT".